# How to "enable remote errors" on a local report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a report designed in Visual Studio 2010 report designer (RDLC).  In testing it on my *local computer*, it does not work and says:

> An error has occurred during report processing. MyDataSetName.

If I examine the exception object (inside the `ReportError` event), I can see an additional note

> For more information about this error, navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

This is a report being rendered in `ProcessingMode.Local`, so none of the articles on enabling remote errors for a SQL server apply.  How do I enable the error message to get the information I need to fix the bug?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. In the **Solution Explorer** right click on your project and select **Properties**
2. There you can find an entry called **StartItem**. Select the report you want to debug
3. In the **tool bar** just right beside the **Start button** you can change the **Solution Configuration** (Debug, DebugLocal, Release, ...). Select **DebugLocal**.
4. Press **Start**

This solution worked for me many times because Visual Studio shows more detailed Information when you use DebugLocal instead of Preview.

Answer (score 1):

This is in work with RDL reports recently but I would assume it would work near the same as underneath the hood they both use the same language by Microsoft.

Generally in my experience SSRS has the WORST DEBUGGING SUPPORT KNOWN TO MAN.  If you are coding in C# or VB.NET and expecting that level of help, sorry SSRS won't do it.  Most of it's errors are like: "thing blew up around this area, good luck"  Generally you have to tinker with the object it is referencing(if it even gives you that).  If it is a dataset I would guess that the dataset has one of a few things wrong that it is not telling you:

1. Are you using permissions to a server you can no longer connect to with credentials that changed or a password update?
2. You have your solution/project under source control and Data Source that was shared or embedded had embedded credentials it just lost some how(Had this happen to me so many times and an error like: "Error during local report processing.").  Test the DataSource and go up from there is a good practice.
3. The Dataset had a portion of it's query, execution plan, types, or structure change and is NOT updating.  Attempt to go into the Dataset and refresh it to ensure it can connect.